# What does this line point to in file structure?

Tags: file, structure

> C:\xampp\htdocs\eve-charinfo/.pheal-cache/722091/n3Yeskd6U90NyJXG5m5O6p5Rid9NVKKfJBaSVx3j9S3xApfAiYhBBSabzZas7VCr/account/APIKeyInfo/

It starts off with generic file structure but then you get to the /. and I can't follow the structure anymore.  What does this path actually specify?

Comment: Sorry, but I left my "random alphanumeric garbage to english" translater magic crystal ball at home. Given it says "eve-charinfo", why don't you contact the EVE Online developers?

Comment: because it isn't a path created by an EvE online product but thank you for your smart ass answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the information you've given, it is probably still (at least supposed to be) a path. "." is a special folder meaning  the same folder. For instance ".\readme.txt" is the file readme.txt in the current path.

**Edit**: I mucked up. In this context, . before a folder is the unix/linux convention to hide a folder. What I said previously would apply if it said ".\" rather then "\.". The hidden folder may not be accessible remotely. If local, you may be able to navigate by displaying it.

"/" is the directory separator used by Unix/Linux type OS's (as opposed to "\" being used in Windows), but many applications (not all) will read them interchangeably.

It is therefore likely that the path referred to is C:\xampp\htdocs\eve-charinfo\.pheal-cache\722091\n3Yeskd6U90NyJXG5m5O6p5Rid9NVKKfJBaSVx3j9S3xApfAiYhBBSabzZas7VCr\account\APIKeyInfo\ - at least off the information given, but .pheal-cache may be a hidden, inaccessible folder.

Comment: If i navigate to the first part of that file path, there isn't another folder marked pheal-cache.  To supply more information this is part of an error messaged generated when trying to execute some php code on a website.

Comment: I made a mistake - reading .\ rather then \. . I just corrected the answer.

Comment: If this answer is correct, it is polite to accept it.